# Vertical tabs does not display properly on github

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, tabs

I coded a vertical tab in **test.html** and it works when I open it up with my browser from my hard drive. It looks like this:

[Correct display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLi0e.png)

but when I open the webpage using github, it no longer display properly. It becomes this:

[Wrong display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSgUR.png)

Please, what could be the problem? This is my code:

```
<script>
    function openFood(evt, foodName) 
    {
        var i, x, tablinks;
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("food");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
        {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
            {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" w3-red", ""); 
            }
                document.getElementById(foodName).style.display = "block";
                evt.currentTarget.className += " w3-red";
        }
  </script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>

  <nav class="w3-sidenav w3-light-grey w3-card-2" id="size">
            <div class="w3-container">
                <h5><b>Category</b></h5>
            </div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablink" onclick="openFood(event, 'Rice')">Rice</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablink" onclick="openFood(event, 'Noodles')">Noodles</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablink" onclick="openFood(event, 'Chicken')">Chicken</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablink" onclick="openFood(event, 'Beef')">Beef</a> 
        </nav>
```

Comment: you sure that the right css is loading? also, don't load your custom css fiest, and then 3rd party sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. My browser blocked parts of the page due to weak encryption.

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3GyK.png)